# Duplicating without referencing in python

Tags: list, python-2.7, reference, duplicates

How can i duplicate a list of lists (or any other types) in a way that the resulting lists are new objects and not references to the old ones? As an example i have the following list of lists:

```
l=[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

what i want as result is:

```
l=[[1,2],[3,4],[1,2],[3,4]]
```

If i do `l*=2` the new sub-lists are references to the old sub-lists. 
Doing `l[0].append("python")` will result in

```
l=[[1,2,'python'],[3,4],[1,2,'python'],[3,4]]
```

Also creating a new list like:

```
l2=list(l)
```

or

```
l2=l[:]
```

doesn't solve the problem. I want to have new sub-lists which are independent of their origin and which upon changing have no impact on their old fellows. How can i do this i python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the best way to copy a nested data structure so that copies get made of all the references (not just the ones at the top level) is to use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html). In your nested list example, you can do:

```
l.extend(copy.deepcopy(l))
```

`deepcopy` will still work even if the data structure contains references to itself, or multiple references to the same object. It usually works for objects stored as attributes on an instances of custom classes too. You can define a `__deepcopy__` method if you want to give a class special copying behavior (e.g. if some of its attributes are bookkeeping data that shouldn't be copied).

Here's a version of your nested list example code using instances of a linked list class rather than Python `list`s. `copy.deepcopy` does the right thing!

```
class linked_list(object):
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.next is not None:
            return "({!r})->{!r}".format(self.value, self.next)
        else:
            return "({!r})".format self.value

lst = linked_list(linked_list(1, linked_list(2)),
                  linked_list(linked_list(3, linked_list(4))))
print(lst) # prints ((1)->(2))->((3)->(4))
lst.next.next = copy.deepcopy(lst)
print(lst) # prints ((1)->(2))->((3)->(4))->((1)->(2))->((3)->(4))
lst.value.value = 5
print(lst) # prints ((5)->(2))->((3)->(4))->((1)->(2))->((3)->(4))
```